# Extracting digits from column and splitting each into separate column

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to iteratively filter out digits from a given set of columns. At most there should be 6 numbers in each column.

I would then like to split each of these columns into 6 separate columns each housing a  number from the 6 numbers extracted.

I have attempted to do this by replacing all strings in the columns of interest with the numbers extracted from that column and the using a for loop to split each of the columns into 6 separate columns:

```
judge_cols = ['JudgeID'+str(i) for i in range(1,85)]
num = lambda x: re.search('\d+',x).group()
for i in judge_cols:
    data[i].replace('\D+',' ',regex=True,inplace=True)
    data[['Judge1BoxerScore'+num(i),'Judge1OppScore'+num(i),
         'Judge2BoxerScore'+num(i),'Judge2OppScore'+num(i),
         'Judge3BoxerScore'+num(i),'Judge3OppScore'+num(i)]] = data[i].str.split(' ',6,expand=True).drop(columns=[0])
```

The problem however is that this returns the error:

```
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

I tried to ensure that the columns would be the same length by dropping column zero from each split. I noticed that when I split a single column to 6 columns there is always column 0 which contains nothing. However this doesn't seem to be helping in this case.

Here is a sample of my data:

```
{'JudgeID1': {0: "['[]', '[]', '[]']",
  1: '[]',
  2: "['[]', '[]', '[]']",
  3: "['[38 38]', '[37 39]', '[38 38]']",
  4: "['[]', '[]', '[]']",
  5: '[]',
  6: "['[]', '[]', '[]']"},
 'JudgeID2': {0: "['[]', '[]', '[]']",
  1: "['[]', '[]', '[]']",
  2: "['[]', '[]', '[]']",
  3: "['[37 37]', '[38 36]', '[38 36]']",
  4: "['[]', '[]', '[]']",
  5: '[]',
  6: "['[]', '[]', '[]']"}}
```

The expected output from this example would resemble this:

```
       A1   B1  C1  D1  E1  F1  A2 B2 C2 D2 E2 F2 
0               
1          
2          
3      38   38  37  39  38  38  37 37 38 36 38 36 
4          
5          
6
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @ChrisA I added an example of what my desired output is

Comment: `df['JudgeID5'].str.extractall(r'(\b\d+\b)').unstack().reindex(df.index)` ..?

Comment: @ChrisA Thanks. I only used JudgeID5 as an example. The problem is when I try do this for all the columns in my dataset

Comment: so what is your full expected output...? including all columns

Comment: @ChrisA updated the sample data and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to [`extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html), then [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html). Finally, we'll do some clean-up by fixing the column names:

```
df_out = (df.stack()
          .str.extractall(r'(\b\d+\b)')
          .unstack([1, 2])
          .droplevel(0, axis=1)
          .sort_index(axis=1)
          .reindex(df.index))


df_out.columns = [f'{j}Boxer{i+1}' if i % 2 == 0 else f'{j}Opp{i+1}'
                  for j, i in df_out.columns]
```